# Understanding what is API wrapper around existing library

Tags: python, api

How to write a python helper API to wrap existing python library.

I have never written anything like this or may be written but not realized it. Can someone tell me what exactly it is and how to do it ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?  Are you working in Python only?  Or are you trying to give some other language/runtime the ability to call into Python code?

Comment: @James Henstridge: I am working in Python only and want to wrap one of existing python library.

Comment: Is it possible that the library the client wants you to wrap isn't written in Python (e.g. it might be C or C++)?  That would make a bit more sense, since it is quite common to talk about wrapping such a library for use in Python.

Comment: @James Henstridge: Ok, I think question is not making any sense ;-) I will try to update it a bit.

Comment: @James Henstridge: Please see the edited question with some more detailed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper over a library combines functionality in that library (and other libraries) in a way that makes that library more useful for whatever you're doing.

For example, here's a set of procedures that might make up one library:

- add(x, y) # returns x + y
- subtract(x, y) # returns x - y

Here's a procedure that "wraps" those procedures:

```
def multiply(x, y):
    product = 0
    for i in xrange(x):
        product = add(product, y)
    return product
```

...and similarly, maybe a divide() procedure.

Comment: Yes, your example makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The process is mostly like this:

1) You write a new library (the wrapper)

2) This library depends on the existing library (the one you are going to wrap)

3) The wrapper will call the underlying library, offering a different API than the orignal library

Usually you want to do this because the orignal library has not developer friendly APIs in the first place.

Howver you do not say why you are supposed to undergo such task. Whoever gave you the task should also be able to give you the rationale for the work. The person giving you the task can exactly tell you what is wantd and how do it. Because there is no details in your question it is impossible to give better answer.

Comment: The OP did say "an API that can wrap *any* existing Python library" (emphasis mine). Your answer looks like it's discussing writing a wrapper for a single given Python library.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa:I can't share the exact requirement since its client confidential. But, actually I just wanted to learn what is the meaning of sentence 'wrap existing library' and how to do it. Sorry, for not being clear.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa: Can you please take any existing python library and provide a simple example of API that wrap the chosen library. It will help me understand it better. Otherwise any link of open source will also do.

Comment: @ Paul D. Waite: Oops, my fault. Yes, I do want to write wrapper for single given python library.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa: Please see the edited question with some more detailed info. I was hesitant to provide initially.

Comment: @user893338: I think this is a matter you should discuss in detail with your client if you do not undestand the requirements and the task in the hand. General guidelines are layed out above... after that it moves domain of a business problem. However, one example in Python world I can think is lxml library which wraps libxml library.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa: Thanks for all the help you provided. But, the example provided by 'Sam the Great' made your answer more valuable. That example pointed me in some direction, hence accepting it as my answer.

Comment: No problem. Best luck for you and your customer.